# Are miniature game army tactics question on topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic

This is in response to this [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7387/2733).

> I just picked up a 40K Necron codex today and I am rather astonished. They appear quite overpowered to me. Then again, I play Orks and Imperial Guard, so maybe that's why they appear so.
>
> My question is for the experienced Necron players: what are the disadvantages in playing Necrons? There's the low initiative (offset by being reasonably tough and numerous), most of the armor values are relatively low (offset by vehicle abilities) and the weapon ranges seem to cluster around 24" (not so bad). So what do you have to watch out for or compensate for when playing your Necrons?

The user is soliciting fairly general discussion about an army in a miniature game.  To me these seem to be out of scope for a the Q/A format.

From the FAQ:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

The 40K blog community and forums have hundreds of pages of posts and discussion on how to play a Necron army.  And consensus on these types of things is hard to find within the 40K community.  Maybe my problem as an active 40K blogger is that I really can imagine it taking a book to answer this question.

On other SE sites I've been on, this question would probably be closed.  Then again a site like roleplaying would probably allow something similar.

So, how broad is too broad when asking about army strategy in a miniature game?

Comment: I think a strong parallel could be made with how Gaming.SE handles questions on Starcraft (and its ilk).  For example, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4016 seem to be scoped similarly to the referenced question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that broad tactical discussion is out of scope.  However, my impression is that this question is actually very narrow.  It's possible to give clear, short, objective answers to this, as the question asks only for the general drawbacks of all Necron armies - which should be a short and simple list.

In particular, the question does not ask what tactics to use to compensate for (or take advantage of) those Necron disadvantages - I agree that question would be unanswerably broad, worthy of a book to itself.  The questioner presumably intends to solve that problem himself, and just wants to know what to address.

(I tried substituting my own favoured 'Eldar' for Necrons in the question, and realised I could write a short, clear, two paragraph answer, without actually having to discuss Eldar tactics.)

Comment: Fair enough.  I think I read too much into this question when I first saw it.